# Moving from Class::DBI to DBIx::Class

Tags: perl, dbix-class, class-dbi

I'm currently doing some research on DBIx::Class in order to migrate my current application from Class::DBI. Honestly I'm a bit disappointed about the DBIx::Class when it comes to configuring the result classes, with Class::DBI I could setup metadata on models just by calling the on function  without a code generator and so on my question is ... can I the same thing with DBIX::Class also it seems that client-side triggers are not supported in DBIx::Class or i'm not looking at the wrong docs?

Comment: bit late now, but i never saw this until now - you should have tagged it with 'perl'

Answer (score 5):

Triggers can be implemented by redefining the appropriate method (new/create/update/delete etc) in the Result class, and calling the parent (via `$self->next::method()`) within it, either before or after your code. Admittedly it's a bit clumsy compared to the before/after triggers in Class::DBI.

As for metadata - are you talking about temporary columns on an object? i.e. data that won't be stored in the database row. These can be added easily using one of the Class::Accessor::* modules on CPAN

One of the hardest changes to make when switching from CDBI to DBIC is to think in terms of ResultSets - often what would have been implemented via a Class method in CDBI becomes a method on a ResultSet - and code may need to be refactored considerably, it's not always a straightforward conversion from one to the other.